# How can I make flyspell ignore urls?

Tags: spell-checking, flyspell, ispell

When I use `flyspell-mode`, it reports spelling errors whenever I type a URL. Is there a way I can tell Flyspell to stop checking URLs?

Comment: For `ispell` (not `flyspell`) this semi-related link, regarding `ispell-skip-region-alist`, looks helpful:  http://superuser.com/a/345461/206164  Perhaps `flyspell` has something similar that can be implemented -- e.g., using `flyspell-mode-predicate`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I found a hint in [this [Superuser.com answer](https://superuser.com/a/345461): you need to set `flyspell-mode-predicate` to a function that will decide whether words should be checked or not.  Here's a way to get Flyspell to ignore anything starting with "http" or "https":

```
(defun flyspell-ignore-http-and-https ()
  "Function used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate' to ignore stuff starting with \"http\" or \"https\"."
  (save-excursion
    (forward-whitespace -1)
    (when (looking-at " ")
        (forward-char)
    (not (looking-at "https?\\b"))))) 

(put 'text-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'flyspell-ignore-http-and-https)
```

There are some shortcomings, of course:

- I'm assuming that anything beginning with "http" or "https" should be skipped; that includes "http://cnn.com" and "https://google.com" (good), but also "httpomatic" and "httpstatisticiansarehip" (presumably bad)
- I'm not bothering with mailto:, ftp:, file:, etc etc. (But that way [may lie madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)...)

But as a quick-and-dirty method, it should work.

Comment: Can we apply this in the latex-mode? and also for the url inside `href{}`?

Answer (score 1):

I've something along these lines (in my case for markdown mode) to be slightly more resistant to some common but pathological cases from Saint Aardvark the Carpeted's answer:

```
(require 'thingatpt)
(defun markdown-flyspell-predicate ()
  (not (thing-at-point 'url)))
(put 'markdown-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'markdown-flyspell-predicate)
```

In particular, if you start by looking at the whitespace before a word, the URL won't necessarily start with `https`. Consider these cases:

```
(https://emacs.stackexchange.com)
[text text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com)
\url{https://emacs.stackexchange.com}
```